# Exact placement for XSL-FO

Tags: ocr, xsl-fo, apache-fop, xml-formatting

I have an item in an XML-FO page ( running through FOP ) when needs exact placement for an OCR. Whenever the page is edited (or an included page) its very difficult to get the OCR line back into place.

Is it possible with FOP to specify exact placement. rather than having the item being pushed around by the previous items on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these suggestions are at the XSL-FO level, which FOP just processes.

I don't know about exact placement, but [this FAQ entry](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#indent-inheritance) may be relevant.  Basically indentation is inherited, so you may need to reset it.

Also; [this link](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#fo-preformat) discusses ways to enable/disable whitespace collapse, etc.

[Another link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xsl-20011015/slice7.html#common-absolute-position-properties) describes using absolute positioning attributes (from CSS) to position `fo:block-containers`

Comment: It can be done, i've used block-container and absolute positioning. To be able to position correctly i've had to put it in static-content.